# WPF Context Menu command Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have tried few solutions given in SO, but still i'm unable to trigger the command.

XAML:

```
 <Image Source="{Binding CurrentImage.Source, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType= Window}}">
     <Image.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                  <MenuItem Header="Edit Image" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.EditImageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
     </Image.ContextMenu>
```

ViewModel:

```
private ICommand _EditImageCommand;
public ICommand EditImageCommand
   {
      get
        {
           return _EditImageCommand ?? (_EditImageCommand = new CommandHandler(() => EditImage(), _canExecute));
        }
   }

 public void EditImage()
 {

 }
```

Comment: That binding via `Tag` and setting `DataContext` fills wrong (especially for `MVVM`). Check binding errors in Output window. It should be enough to set path only in `Command` binding normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have changed my XAML to,

```
<Window.Resources>
        <local:ImageList x:Key="SliderViewModel"></local:ImageList>
</Window.Resources>

    <Image Source="{Binding CurrentImage.Source, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <Image.ContextMenu>
               <ContextMenu>
                     <MenuItem Header="Edit Image" Command="{Binding EditImageCommand, Source={StaticResource SliderViewModel}}"></MenuItem>
                 </ContextMenu>
         </Image.ContextMenu>
     </Image>
```

Working fine. Thanks

Comment: Yes ofcourse it worked only after changing the command to public along with the XAML changes. Thanks you helped at right point.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
private ICommand _EditImageCommand;
private ICommand EditImageCommand
   {
      get
        {
           return _EditImageCommand ?? (_EditImageCommand = new CommandHandler(() => EditImage(), _canExecute));
        }
   }

 public void EditImage()
 {

 }
```

to

```
private ICommand _EditImageCommand;
public ICommand EditImageCommand // has to be public
   {
      get
        {
           return _EditImageCommand ?? (_EditImageCommand = new CommandHandler(() => EditImage(), _canExecute));
        }
   }

 public void EditImage()
 {

 }
```

Commands have to be public to be accessed (or internal for the sake of correctness).

Also, change your xaml to:

```
<Image Source="{Binding CurrentImage.Source, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType= Window}}">
     <Image.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                  <MenuItem Header="Edit Image" Command="{Binding EditImageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
     </Image.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Have changed, but still it doesn't.

Comment: Check my edit. Is your DataContext of the window you are in the viewmodel you posted? Why do you use the Relative source self?

Answer (score 1):

Another nice workaround is to declare a static instance of your view model in App.xaml: `<ViewModelTypeName x:Key="ViewModelName" d:IsDataSource="True" />`and bind like this `Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelName}, Path=MyCommand}"` I had the same issue when i needed to bind from Window and menuitem's native DataContext simultaneously. Also this solution looks not that complicated.